# ListView Items are not displayed when adding a HeaderView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I've a listView that consist of 2 parts , the header part is an image and the second part is the list items . 
I've tried this code :

```
myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, titles, images);
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_main_randomimage, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(view);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

when I run it , it only shows the header part and no item shows . 
I want to have both parts on the listView

How can I have both of them in the listView ?

thanks

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: The code should add the header to the list and the items aswell. I think you need to modify you r ListView Height from the layout. Set it to something static(250dip) and then execute.

Comment: can you please let me know have given fix height to header or wrap ?

Answer (score 0):

Try inflating your Header `View` like this:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(Context).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Also, whats inside your activity_main_randomimage .xml file? And whats the code of your adapter?